# Is possible I import a cocos project into Unreal 4?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, unreal-engine4

Consider they all C++ language, is similar in the low-level code. So i want to know does the Undreal 4 have any function can help me import the cocos project?

Answer (score 0):

No. This is like asking can I study some law book by reading Lord of the Rings since they are both written in English and share the same grammar.

Unreal Engine has it's own ecosystem and specifies how things it's own way. Cocos2d is
a collection of frameworks. They are very different pieces of software.

Of course you can manually build something similar in UE than you have in Cocos and may
be able to reuse some logic.